# Keep track of where lookup items were used

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, lookup-column

I have a custom list A that has a lookup field for items in a custom list B, is there a way to know where a list B item was used in the list A?

edit:

I'll try to give an example, say A is a list of stores and B is a list of products. I have a lookup column on list A that references the products on list B (which products does this store sell) and my question is: If i have a product (item from B), can i know which stores sell it (which items in A reference in their lookup column the item from B)?

[image: List A lookup column referencing B list items]

A has the lookup column and item 1 and 4 reference item 2 from list B, if just given 2 from B, can i know which items from A are referencing B?

[image: B knows what references him?]

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question with example or can you rephrase the question for better understanding.

Comment: Is this is what you want? http://pawansatope.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-count-related-lookup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To know which items from A are referencing B?**

- Create a custom view at Store List (A).

  - List Settings > at Below of page > Click create a View.
- Set its name.
- Select the column that you need to show.
- At `Group by` section select the Lookup field from Products (B)
- Also, at `Totals` select it to show count beside each product.

This should list all items at store list (A) grouped by all Products at (B) with its count.

Comment: I did as you said but the lookup field doesn't show up at the "Group by" or "Totals" sections (all the others do).

Comment: this lookup field is multiple or signal selection , please share your lookup field settings

Comment: is multiple selection

Comment: it only shows without multiple selections , and at your above image, you make relation one to many from B to A so why you need it multiple ? Please tell me if you need more clarification

Comment: Because, staying at the example logic, a store can sell more than one product, i.e. A item can have more than one B items associated (https://puu.sh/qK7jb/fdf77dad0f.png my lookup field settings)

Comment: In this case, multiple selection checks this old link that may help you http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2010/04/15/sharepoint-group-by-a-column-with-multiple-values-aspx/